# Denied access to user to some parts of my project

Tags: django

I have a system that will consist in 7 modules and I need to denied access to users to some modules of the system, I'm creating an app for each module, is there something in the Django admin that can help me with this or I have to do it in other way?

Comment: You can leverage groups to grant/revoke permissions on a model-level basis: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, so the best I can do is point you in the [right direction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization).

You can make [specific permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) for users too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many parts of your site should be public, but if you have too many private views this could be useful https://github.com/dabapps/django-private-views